# Error mixing types with Eigen matrices

Tags: c++, casting, eigen

There was no quick find answer that I could see on stack for this problem so I thought I would add one.

Say I have the following example code from the c++ Eigen Library:

```
Eigen::Matrix4d m1;
Eigen::Matrix4f m2;
m1 << 1, 2, 3, 4 ... 16
m2 = m1; //Compile error here.
```

I get a compile error on the final line that boils down to this:

```
YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY
```

What is an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

So the way to fix this which took me an annoyingly long time to find is to use the derived `cast` method described [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a660200abaf1fc4b888330a37d6132b76). Now the definition is this:

```
internal::cast_return_type<Derived,const CwiseUnaryOp<internal::scalar_cast_op<typenameinternal::traits<Derived>::Scalar, NewType>, const Derived> >::type cast() const
```

Which Ill admit, phased me a little. But turns out it is pretty easy (and the only explanation I could find was in the Eigen 2.0 doc which was frustrating). All you need to do is this:

```
m2 = m1.cast<float>();
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Any suggestion on how the documentation could be improved to make this easier to find?

Comment: @JitseNiesen Well the Eigen 2.0 had really good documentation for this: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-2.0/TutorialCore.html But it is difficult to find now that Eigen3 is the standard.